# Can't use imported library. Android Studio. Google cloud endpoints jar

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine, android-studio

## Background

I've created a basic python app engine application with endpoint annotations. I used the python console tool to export a java client library (jar) file ([Based on this example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/setup#generating_the_client_library_for_the_backend_api)). I've used the "add as library" and verified that the gradle file up[image: gradle]

## Issue

I'm not attempting to import the jar file into Android Studio 0.5.2. I followed the directions in the example but can't seem to get access to the models in my jar file. [Based on this part of the example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/create_app#add_an_application_class_for_local_data_storage) I should be able to import my library and use the models like any other class.

[image: import screen capture]

When I add the ";" Android Studio deletes my import line and sets an error:
[image: error message]

> Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only.
>   Details: Current thread: Thread[JobScheduler FJ pool 3/4,6,main] 570719363
>   Our dispatch thread:Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 0.5.2#AI-135.1078000, eap:true,6,main] 12400241
>   SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 0.5.2#AI-135.1078000, eap:true,6,main] 12400241
>   java.lang.Throwable
>       at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:124)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1085)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertIsDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:1073)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.assertDispatchThread(FocusManagerImpl.java:1159)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.getFocusOwner(FocusManagerImpl.java:888)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.getFocusOwner(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:119)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$2.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:202)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.getActiveSplitters(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:230)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.getSplitters(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1180)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.getCurrentEditorWithProviderComposite(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1258)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.getEditors(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1230)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonListeners.canUndo(DaemonListeners.java:390)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonListeners.canChangeFileSilently(DaemonListeners.java:386)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.config.QuickFixFactoryImpl.timeToOptimizeImports(QuickFixFactoryImpl.java:741)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.config.QuickFixFactoryImpl.access$000(QuickFixFactoryImpl.java:70)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.intention.impl.config.QuickFixFactoryImpl$1.isAvailable(QuickFixFactoryImpl.java:621)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ShowIntentionsPass.addAvailableActionsForGroups(ShowIntentionsPass.java:129)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ShowIntentionsPass.access$000(ShowIntentionsPass.java:69)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ShowIntentionsPass$1.process(ShowIntentionsPass.java:88)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ShowIntentionsPass$1.process(ShowIntentionsPass.java:85)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonCodeAnalyzerImpl$6.process(DaemonCodeAnalyzerImpl.java:545)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonCodeAnalyzerImpl$6.process(DaemonCodeAnalyzerImpl.java:539)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonCodeAnalyzerEx$1.process(DaemonCodeAnalyzerEx.java:59)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonCodeAnalyzerEx$1.process(DaemonCodeAnalyzerEx.java:53)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl$IntervalNode.processAliveKeys(IntervalTreeImpl.java:97)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl.processOverlappingWith(IntervalTreeImpl.java:468)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl.processOverlappingWith(IntervalTreeImpl.java:463)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl.processOverlappingWith(IntervalTreeImpl.java:476)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl.processOverlappingWith(IntervalTreeImpl.java:476)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl.processOverlappingWith(IntervalTreeImpl.java:463)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl.processOverlappingWith(IntervalTreeImpl.java:463)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl.processOverlappingWith(IntervalTreeImpl.java:463)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.IntervalTreeImpl.processOverlappingWith(IntervalTreeImpl.java:440)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.MarkupModelImpl.processRangeHighlightersOverlappingWith(MarkupModelImpl.java:264)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonCodeAnalyzerEx.processHighlights(DaemonCodeAnalyzerEx.java:53)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonCodeAnalyzerImpl.processHighlightsNearOffset(DaemonCodeAnalyzerImpl.java:539)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ShowIntentionsPass.getAvailableActions(ShowIntentionsPass.java:85)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ShowIntentionsPass.getActionsToShow(ShowIntentionsPass.java:260)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ShowIntentionsPass.getIntentionActionsToShow(ShowIntentionsPass.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ShowIntentionsPass.doCollectInformation(ShowIntentionsPass.java:186)
>       at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:61)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:380)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1153)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:371)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:368)
>       at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:344)
>       at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:193)
>       at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>       at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:858)
>       at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1687)
>       at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1642)
>       at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:109)

The error message contains 4 sections that look very similar to the above.

I've searched searched everywhere and seem to be at a loss. Using this library is crucial to my project and I've already spent 10+ hours trying to resolve this issue on my own. Any tips or guidance is very much appreciated.

## UPDATE

Feedback from @Scott has resolved the disappearing import issue but I still can't seem to access the objects in the jar.
[image]

Anyone know if this looks to be an issue with the jar, gradle or Android studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is a bug in Android Studio and is actually a red herring; it's not the cause of your problem. You have **Preferences** > **Editor** > **Auto import** > **Optimize imports on the fly** enabled. When you type that `import` and press <kbd>;</kbd>, it optimizes the import away because you're not using it yet. Either disable the preference, or don't type `import` statements manually -- use a reference to the class in your code, and let the editor assistance add the `import` for you.

Comment: thank you for the quick feedback. Turning off import on the fly eliminated my error but I still can't seem to access the objects in the jar file. I'll update my original post in hopes you might have any additional feedback.

Comment: I have created a separate question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597097/using-client-library-from-cloud-endpoints-jar-import-not-working) that focuses on my unanswered question. This answer fixed my import disappearing issue.